# Keep trailing zeros in bigdecimal in json

Tags: jsonserializer

I have created onse serializer class which should restrict Bigdecimal to tow digits after decimal. But its removing zeros too. For ex: if value is 95.50, its truncating zero and output as 95.5 in json.

```
public class PriceJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer {

    @Override
    public void serialize(BigDecimal value, JsonGenerator jgen, 
    SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException 
    {
      jgen.writeNumber(value.setScale(2, 
         BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toString());
         }
    }
```

Comment: any answer on this?

Answer (score 1):

To force the serializer to preserve your rounding without writing the value as a string, try "writeRawValue".

```
public class PriceJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer {

    @Override
    public void serialize(BigDecimal value, JsonGenerator jgen, 
    SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException 
    {
      jgen.writeRawValue(value.setScale(2, 
         BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).toString());
         }
    }
```

Comment: JsonGenerator doesn't have a `writeRawValue` method. Where did you find that reference? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/stream/JsonGenerator.html#method.summary

Comment: I was referring to the Jackson databind classes. I assumed that was the library in question here, as the syntax used is exactly the syntax used by  com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator and com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer  https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator.html The javax class you linked doesn't have a "writeNumber" method either, so I'm pretty sure the original poster was referring to the Jackson library